# Switch cursor from editor to file explorer and vice versa in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a shortcut to switch from editor to file explorer (and vice versa) on vscode ?
I have yet to find one.
Thanks you for your help.

Comment: You can get a list of default keyboard short-cuts for your OS at **Help/ Keyboard Shortcuts Reference**. The command you're looking for is **Explorer / Toggle focus**.

Comment: Everyone here missed the "vice versa" part of your question. To move back to the editor window, use Cmd+1. I'm guessing on PC/Linux, it's Ctrl+1 (or maybe Alt+1).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Please try the `View: Show Explorer` shortcut key, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>.

Answer (score 9):

For macOS, use `shift`+`cmd`+`E`. Note that if the hotkey is also occupied by another program on your mac, you may need to disable it in the preferences of the program before it tasks effect in VSCode.

Answer (score 4):

#### Focus the file explorer

`ctrl+shift+e` focuses the file explorer on Windows, and I think `cmd+shift+e`  focuses the file explorer on on MacOS; but in Ubuntu (at least), `ctrl+shift+e` in an editor is the emoji shortcut, which is why I added this chord:

```json
{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+r",
  "command": "revealFileInOS",
  "when": "!editorFocus"
}
```

The command `revealFileInOS` focuses the file explorer at the current file.

To add or change a keyboard shortcut, press `ctrl+k`, then `ctrl+s` (on Linux or Windows).

#### Focus an editor

To focus an editor pane, use `ctrl+N` on Linux or Windows, `cmd+N` on a Mac), where N is the pane number starting at 1.

Most commonly, you'll have a single pane, so it would be `ctrl+1` on Linux or Windows, `cmd+1` on a Mac.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately <kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd> + <kbd>`Shift`</kbd> + <kbd>`e`</kbd> doesn't do the trick for me, as I utilize various vim setups within vscode. This makes working around <kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd> keys often complex.

I can confirm that @MohamedNaleem's answer works *when I turn off various vim integrations*. If you don't use vim, I suggest sticking with the built-in.

#### My solution Focus & Visibility

I use the chord <kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd>+<kbd>`Space`</kbd> <kbd>`e`</kbd> to switch between the explorer and open editors. It feels nice and ergonomic to me -- all I do is hit the <kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd> and <kbd>`Space`</kbd> keys together and the <kbd>`e`</kbd> key quickly afterwards.

> *Notice the intentionally missing`+` between <kbd>`Space`</kbd> and <kbd>`e`</kbd> when notating the chord.*

#### Δ What to change in Keyboard Shortcuts Δ

The commands you're looking for are

1. `Explorer: Focus on Folders View`, and
2. `View: Toggle Side Bar Visibility`.

To change them simply bring up your command pallet (type <kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd> + <kbd>`Shift`</kbd> + <kbd>`P`</kbd>), type `keyboard`, select `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts`, and input the two shortcut commands above to search.

Double click to select and type your new <kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd> + <kbd>`Space`</kbd> <kbd>`e`</kbd> chord. <kbd>`Enter`</kbd> or <kbd>`Return`</kbd> to confirm. Voila!

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is scouring the web for a solution which allows `<C-h>` (`Ctrl + h`) and `<C-l>` (`Ctrl + l)` to be used with vim keybindings to easily move from:

- 1st editor group (farthest left pane) to the file explorer
- File explorer back to 1st editor group

This is similar to the functionality I remember when using [NerdTree](https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree) in regular `vim`.

Here's my hack:

```js
// keybindings.json (open with Ctrl/Command + Shift + P) and search for JSON
// Keyboard shortcuts
[
    // ...snip
    // I already remap <C-w> h,j,k,l to <C-h>, <C-j>, etc
    {
        "key": "ctrl+h",
        "command": "workbench.action.focusLeftGroup",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && vim.active && vim.mode != 'Insert'"
    },
    {
        // Special case: when in first editor group (pane), go to sidebar
        // if visible.
        "key": "ctrl+h",
        "command": "workbench.explorer.fileView.focus",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && vim.active && vim.mode != 'Insert' && activeEditorGroupIndex == 1 && explorerViewletVisible"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+l",
        "command": "workbench.action.focusRightGroup",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && vim.active && vim.mode != 'Insert'"
    },
    {
        // Special case: when in file explorer, go right (back to 1st open
        // editor group)
        "key": "ctrl+l",
        "command": "workbench.action.focusFirstEditorGroup",
        "when": "filesExplorerFocus"
    },
    // ...snip
]
```

**Note:** I had to remove some `ctrl + l` keybindings that were floating around in VS Code's keyboard shortcuts before this would work. See item 2 in the list below for help debugging keyboard shortcuts.

Some helpful references I found during my search for answers:

1. [VS Code's *undocumented* 'when' clause contexts](https://dev.to/whitphx/find-vscodes-undocumented-when-clause-contexts-1p2g)
2. [VS Code's **documented** 'when' clause contexts](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts#available-context-keys)
3. [How to debug VS Code keybindings (SO answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46140269/how-to-debug-keybinds-in-visual-studio-code)
4. [Vim Keybinding cheat sheet](https://blog.codepen.io/2014/02/21/vim-key-bindings/)