CTRL + V and CTRL + SHIFT + V not working in Vscode
The CTRL + V and CTRL + SHIFT + V keys do not work in Vscode, I changed everything in the hotkeys, but to no avail. I'm using Fedora 41 Hyperland ML4W. It’s interesting that everything works in the GNOME shell, but not in Vscode, and also everything works in the Linux terminal, but not in VS code; in the system itself, CTRL + V and CTRL + SHIFT + V work, and you can also insert text in Vscode,
copied earlier only from Vscode.
I try change keyboards

Hotkeys, means you checked "File->Preferences->Keyboard Shortcuts"? (Similiar to Shortcut for Copy/Paste not work in VSCode)

see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64420753/724039  Which has a link to "To troubleshoot keybindings problems, you can execute the command ....."

This is Ctrl + V or Ctrl + Shift + V setup in VSCode.

Please verify with yours Keyboard Shortcut configuration.
If not working reset the Keyboard Shortcut.
Alternative way:
In VSCode, press Ctrl + Shift + P to open the Command Palette.
Now type Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON) and select it.
Which opens keybindings.json file.
Search & Verify your searched shortcut key information.

All my hotkeys are unchanged and correspond to the photo

Is that shortcuts working properly outside VSCode, I mean other editors in your system ? @ИскандерБакиров
